# What is a message in JS/Node.js event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I'm reading about Event Loop in JS and Node.js, I'm reading these two articles:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop
http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/

They both refer to some messages:

> a **message** queue
>
> A JavaScript runtime contains a **message** queue, which is a list of **messages** to be processed. To each **message** is associated a function
>
> When the operation has been completed, a **message** is enqueued along with the provided callback function. At some point in the future, the **message** is dequeued and the callback fired

and so on.

And they do not explain what a message is, how they are created, what a programmer has to do to make JS/Node.js runtimes create a message, etc.

Particularly, I want to understand what layer those messages belong to in Node.js:

- a Node.js layer,
- `libuv` layer or
- JS layer?

What place do they occupy in Node.js runtime? Which of those three components processes them?

For example, where are messages in this piece of code? What messages and how many of them are created in Event Loop/Node.js/JS/libuv when this piece of code is run?

```
function requestHandler(req, res) {
   db.getUser(req.params.uid, function(err, user) {
       res.end(user.username);
   });
}
```

Comment: I think they're probably referring to what [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-loops) calls a _"task queue"_.  Depending on what `db.getUser` does in your example, it may or may not result in a new task on the queue - if it's synchronous, it won't.  Using `setTimeout` / `setInterval` may be a better example that uses core functionality to explain things.

Comment: I'd say messages are the objects that interface between the libuv and js layer. Nothing that a node.js programmer needs to care about (or even interact with them). In your example piece of code, there probably are too many messages to list them all, hidden too deeply inside the db and http code.

Comment: [message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) is just a generic term. You probably could just as well say "event".

Comment: @Bergi, Thank you. I want to understand those messages from the perspective of blocking the Event Loop. What messages can cause event loop to freeze.

Comment: @Green: It's not the messages that freeze the event loop, it's when the processing of them (the JS code) takes too long.